# How to delete a managed object when inverse relation is unset/reset?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

This is what i've got:

I have Entity Department and Entity Employee in Core Data model.
Department has many Employees, and an Employee has only one Department (inverse).
I have set delete rule on Department to cascade.

Let's say my Department currently has the Employees Judy and Ron.

My question is how can I make sure Judy and Ron are deleted when I set the employees relation of the department to a NSSet of other employees like so:

```
[department setEmployees:someOtherEmployeesSet];
```

I.e. I am overriding the employees field of the department and want the previous employees be deleted immediately.

Currently if I do this, they are still in Core Data:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Employee"];
NSArray* allEmployees = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
NSLog(@"Employees: %@", [allEmployees debugDescription]);
```

This will output the following for Judy and Ron in the console: (does not look like they are deleted)

```
<Employee: 0x14e33620> (entity: Employee; id: 0x14e43230 <x-coredata://4A73CA04-
C30C-44B4-88D5-73179F3A065F/Employee/p2> ; data: <fault>),
<Employee: 0x14e48880> (entity: Employee; id: 0x14e43c10 <x-coredata://4A73CA04-
C30C-44B4-88D5-73179F3A065F/Employee/p3> ; data: <fault>)
```

What do I have to do so that Judy and Ron will be deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delete rules (such as "Cascade") are only applied if the department object is
deleted. In your case, you have to delete the "previous employees" explicitly
before assigning a new set:

```
NSSet *oldEmployees = department.employees;
for (Employee *e in oldEmployees) {
    [context deleteObject:e];
}
department.employees = someOtherEmployeesSet;
```